# Filter outgoing CAN messages in CANoe

Tags: can-bus, canoe

Assuming a number of different nodes and models for remaining bus simulation in CANoe produce and send out CAN frames, what is the general way to prevent CANoe to send out a message with a certain frame ID onto the (real) CAN bus? Filtering seems to only consider *incoming* messages.

There are different ways to tell the nodes to not send a frame (by interacting with the IL settings), but is there a general way? CANalyzer seems to have the possibility to insert nodes into the bus/evaluation tree that are not transparent to frames, but I neither see this option in CANoe nor could I confirm that this works for *outgoing* messages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add output filters in the simulation setup to each simulated node.

Right click on the leg that is connecting the node to the bus. Then choose `Output` -> `Insert Filter`.

This inserts a small node between the ECU and the bus. By double-clicking on the node you can configure which messages to be filtered out.

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to configure this bus-wide. I.e. you would have to do this node-by-node.

HTH

Comment: To add to the unfortunate: While the nodes themselves are exposed and it's possible to disable them via the COM API, there is no option to insert them there either. Looks like manual will have to be it for now